# Boyd & Vandenberghe, Problem 9.6 — Gradient descent step for a quadratic function

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

The question in Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) is very simple — calculate the gradient descent step of a quadratic function. However, the given answer is very confusing. How can we directly get the equation (**yellow part in the picture given below**) without any further information?

[image: link_to_the_problem_picture]

Comment: The yellow does not make sense to me. It's not even correct for $k=0$. I think it should be $\begin{bmatrix} (1-t)^k \gamma \\ (1-\gamma t)^k\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Comment: [Listed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)

Answer (score 3):

The question is why
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(k)}\\x_2^{(k)}\end{bmatrix}=
\left(\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}\right)^k\begin{bmatrix}\gamma\\(-1)^k\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is because for all previous steps the step $t$ is chosen to be optimal (from the *exact line search*). For example, the first step for the initial point $(\gamma,1)$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_1^{(1)}\\x_2^{(1)}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}(1-t)\gamma\\1-\gamma t\end{bmatrix}.
$$
To pick the optimal $t$, we need to minimise
$$
\frac12(x_1^2+\gamma x_2^2)=\frac12(1-t)^2\gamma^2+\frac12\gamma(1-\gamma t)^2.
$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $t$ and setting the derivative to zero gives
$$
t_{opt}=\frac{2}{\gamma+1}, \qquad 1-t_{opt}=\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1},\qquad 1-\gamma t_{opt}=-\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma+1}.
$$
Doing that for all other iterations you get the yellow formula.